# Tengo un error al subir datos a la base de datos

Tags: php, mysql, web

tengo un problema al subir la datos, al darle en registrarse me manda el mensaje de que "supuestamente" la funcion execute() devolvió "true", pero al revisar mi db no aparece nada de los datos.

estoy usando PDO y asi tengo los codigos:
controller.php (el que recibe los datos del formulario)

```
<?php 

class MvcController {
    public function Template () {
        include 'Views/Templated/template.php';
    }    

    public function NavPageLoginController(){
        if (isset($_GET['nav'])){
            $link = $_GET['nav'];
        } else {
            $link = "Login";
        }

        $request = NavPageLogin::LinkPageLogin($link);
        include $request;
    }

    public function NavPageController() {
        if (isset($_GET['nav'])) {
            $link = $_GET['nav'];
        } else {
            $link = "Home";
        }
        $request = NavPage::LinkPage($link);
        include $request;
    }

    public function RegisterUserController(){
        if (isset($_POST['ci'])) {
            $date = 0;
            $access = 0;
            $Data = array("name" => $_POST['name'], 
                          "surname" => $_POST['surname'],
                          "email" => $_POST['email'],
                          "password" => $_POST['password'],
                          "year" => $_POST['year'],
                          "ci" => $_POST['ci'],
                          "country" => $_POST['country'],
                          "photo" => $_FILES['photoprofile'],
                          "date" => $date,
                          "access" => $access);

            $request = Data::RegisterUserModel($Data, "users");
            if ($request == "success") {
                echo "Listo";
            }
        }
    }

}
?>
```

CRUD.php (el que se encarga de las consultas y enviarlas de nuevo al Controller)

```
    <?php require 'Models/CORE.php';

class Data extends Connection {
    public function RegisterUserModel($data, $table){
        if ($data['photo']){
                global $dirupload;
                global $rupload;
                $ci = $data['ci'];
                $dirupload = "photoprofile/$ci/";

                $photo = $data['photo'];
                $namephoto = $photo['name'];
                $nameTmp = $photo['tmp_name'];
                $rupload = "{$dirupload}profile.jpg";
                $extArchive = preg_replace( '/image\//', '', $photo['type'] );

                if( $extArchive == 'jpeg' || $extArchive == 'png') {

                    if( !file_exists( $dirupload ) ) {
                        mkdir( $dirupload, 775, true );
                    }

                    if( move_uploaded_file( $nameTmp, $rupload ) ) {
                        return true;
                    } else {
                        return false;
                    }

                } else {
                    $photoinvalid = true;
                }
        }
        $stmt = Connection::Connect()->prepare("INSERT INTO $table(name, surname, email, pass, ci, year, country, rupload) VALUES (:name,:surname,:email,:password,:year,:ci,:country,:photo)");

        $stmt->bindParam(':name', $data['name'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(':surname', $data['surname'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(':email', $data['email'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(':password', $data['password'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(':year', $data['year'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindParam(':ci', $data['ci'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindParam(':country', $data['country'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(':photo', $rupload, PDO::PARAM_LOB);

        if ($stmt->execute()) {
            return "success";
        } else {
            return "error";
        }
    }
}


?>
```

lo mas raro es que si cambio la palabra "success" por cualquier otra, me sigueimprimiendo la palabra Listo que es lo que me tiene confundido. Gracias de antemano

Comment: No creo que para el caso de la imagen que subas debas usar PDO::PARAM_STR puesto que es un archivo no una cadena de texto

Comment: Debería ser PDO::PARAM_LOB

Comment: En la llamada a `RegisterUserModel()` le estas pasando una variable `$table` no definida en el ámbito, en lugar del array de datos, `$Data`.

Comment: @Xerif si, efectivamente, pero ese error ya lo había solucionado solo que cuando subí el código no me percaté de solucionarlo

Comment: @ShadowPaz pero no quiero subir la imagen, la imagen será almacenada en el servidor y en la DB solo será almacenada su ruta. ahora bien, probando el cambio que me sugeriste sigue sin funcionar. lo que me parece mas raro es             if ($request == "success") {
                echo "Listo";
            }. al cambiar la palabra success por cualquier otra me sigue imprimiendo el Listo, algo que no debería suceder

Comment: @DanielParra Utiliza `mysqli::$error` para determinar si hay algun problema con el sql. http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.error.php

Comment: @Xerif man ya conseguí el error, era el return que tenia al verificar la subida de la imagen jejeje un error simple que me llevo medio dia de atraso. xD gracias a todos!